# Using bash "&" operator with ";" delineator?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a command that's a one-line for loop containing a command that uses the & operator to put the command in the background:

```
for dir in $(ls); do command $dir &; done
```

Where `&` tells BASH to run `command` in the background. Yet BASH returns

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

What's going on here? How can I use `&` in conjunction with `;`? I tried enclosing things in quotes, like `do "command $dir &"` or `do command $dir "&"` but those have unexpected results.

Comment: Beware using `$(ls)` in place of `*` is generally considered a **bad practice**.  Because of the nature of globbing `*` will allow you to deal with filenames that contain whitespace, `$(ls)` will not.  Consider a list of files, "one a", "one b", "two".  With `$(ls)` you will iterate "one", "a" "one", "b", "two".  With `*` you will iterate the actual file list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't use the `;` with '&', the '&' on its own is enough to finish the command. I believe there is currently no mention of this behaviour in the manual. Your loop would simply be:

```
for dir in $(ls); do command $dir & done
```

Additionally, you should consider using a glob instead of `$(ls)` which will fail if the filename contains whitespace. You can set `nullglob` to prevent `dir` being a `*` if there are no files:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for dir in *; do command $dir & done
```

Comment: There's no mention because `;`, `&`, `&&`, `||`, and `\n` are all command separators, some of which have different meanings than others.

Comment: +1 `for dir in $(ls); do command $dir ;; done` will throw the same error, as will `for f in $(ls); do echo $f |;done` etc.