# How to create port listeners in Linux machine?

Tags: shell-script, networking

Below command creates a port listener:

```
nc –l 5500 &
```

as shown below:

```
[root@xyz ~]# netstat -anlp | grep 5500
tcp       0     0 0.0.0.0:5500               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
   21085/nc
```

---

I would like to create 100 port listeners.

But below syntax:

```
 $ for i in {10000..10100}; do nc -l $i &; done
```

gives error:

```
 bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

---

1. How to create n port listeners, just for testing?
2. How to delete those port listeners, after completion of testing?

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505843/cant-run-a-background-process-and-other-command-from-bash-in-one-line-unxepect or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271714/run-the-same-command-multiple-times-in-background and/or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110822/using-bash-operator-with-delineator

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56063706#56063706), the `&` is a statement terminator, just like `;`, so the `;` before `done` shouldn't be there:

```
for i in {10000..10100}; do nc -l "$i" & done
```

or,

```
for i in {10000..10100}; do
    nc -l "$i" &
done
```

You may kill all your `nc` processes using `pkill nc`.

Alternatively, save the PIDs of each `nc` process in an array and kill them using this array:

```
pids=()
for i in {10000..10100}; do
    nc -l "$i" & pids+=("$!")
done
```

Later:

```
kill "${pids[@]}"
```

This obviously assumes that none of the `nc` commands' PIDs have been recycled for other processes.

---

As roaima points out in comments, the brace expansion `{10000..10100}` expands to 101 numbers, not 100.